# Place the Caption of a Figure at the Top of a Figure

Tags: floats, captions

After trying many of the community's proposals and failing to **place the title of the figure at the top**.

I thought that I could redefine the default figure in latex, specifically the one corresponding to the document class article, if they are different depending on the class.

I saw something similar but now I can't find it.

Comment: Do you have tried `caption` package?

Comment: what do you mean by the title of the figure?  in article class figures have captions given by `\caption` and it is placed where you place it in the source above or below the image depending if `\caption` is before or after `\includegraphics`

Comment: I use rmarkdown and knitr

Comment: What would be the parameters to define the caption of figures at the top when including the package caption? `usepackage[PARAMETERS]{caption}`

Comment: sure but this is a latex question, the default code in article class does not position the caption at all so it's like asking to write `two one` instead of `one two` latex does nothing here, it just outputs the caption and image in the order you write them, so it is very hard to answer your question.

Comment: Are you talking about swapping \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip, or doing something nasty like floatrow?  (See page 35)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written in `markdown` and compiled with `knitr`, you can have the caption at the top like this:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{floatrow}
  - \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
---
```{r message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r fig.cap="Diamonds", message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
ggplot(data=diamonds,aes(x=price,y=carat,colour=cut)) + geom_point()
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hope that this is self-explanatory.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Provides example-image afaik.
\usepackage{graphicx}

% for [H] placement option (force manually defined position)
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\figurename~\ref{fig:CaptionAbove}} has the caption \textbf{above} and \textbf{\figurename~\ref{fig:CaptionBelow}} has the caption \textbf{below}.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption Above}
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image}
    %\caption{Caption Below}
    \label{fig:CaptionAbove}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    %\caption{Caption Above}
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Caption Below}
    \label{fig:CaptionBelow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]